# PC crashing when streaming radio in 1st minute of boot into Windows 11

Tags: audio, windows-11

Windows 11 Pro 64-bit.
Realtek High Definition Audio

When I open Chrome and start streaming music from a radio station website, the computer will hang if I do so within, say, the first 60 seconds of booting into Windows.

If I start streaming from the same website after around 60 seconds of booting into Windows, the computer will be fine.

If I check the Windows event log, nothing stands out.

Device Manager says `Realtek High Definition Audio` `This device is working properly`.

I've tried updating the drivers of the sound card to default ones, and the issue remains.

I've tried running the Windows troubleshooter for sound problems, and it replaced the drivers with generic drivers, and the issue remains.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like reinstalling the audio drivers from the PC manufacturer website has resolved this issue.